# jQuery validate in tabs only works on first submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-tabs

I am trying to solve the issue where I have required form fields hidden behind tabs.

I have managed to get this half working so that when you click the submit button any required+hidden fields, it will auto display this tab.

But the problem is when you:
1. Load the page, click submit and this works fine.
2. Go back to the first tab and click the submit again and nothing happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/3xEch/

```
// Form validator
var theForms = $("form[method=post]:not(.noValidate)");
if (theForms.length){
    theForms.each(function(){
        var $dis = $(this);

        if($dis.hasClass("validateHidden")){
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                ignore: ''
            });
        }

        validater = $dis.validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var trigger = element.next('.ui-datepicker-trigger, .input-label');
                if(!trigger.length){ trigger = element.parent('label'); }
                var labelWidth = element.parent("p").not(".full").find("label").eq(0).width();
                error.insertAfter(trigger.length > 0 ? trigger : element)
                     .css("marginLeft", labelWidth);

                // Check if hidden inside tab
                if(element.parents(".tab").is(":hidden")){
                    var tabs = element.parents(".tabs");
                    tabs.find(".tab").hide();
                    var tab = $("#"+element.parents(".tab").attr("id"));
                    tab.show();
                    tabs.find(".tabmenu li").removeClass("selected");
                    tabs.find(".tabmenu li").eq(tab.index()-1).addClass("selected");
                }
            }
        });

        $('.tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(){
            validater.resetForm();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `errorPlacement` is called only once for each element which is validated.

See this question: [jQuery Validation Plugin: Invoke errorPlacement function when onfocusout, keyup and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400607/jquery-validation-plugin-invoke-errorplacement-function-when-onfocusout-keyup)

They recommend using the `showErrors` method for any repeated validations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running this code on `$(document).ready()` - run this code whenever the first tab is displayed? Im guessing that the code doesn't work after the first time because the events are bound to HTML elements that are cleared when another tab is clicked on.