# Place Error Messages for the same field in different Locations jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

So I am doing a required check and a digits check on the same input field. I have the error messages appearing however I want the required message to appear to the right of a div and digits error message to appear at the bottom of the page. I thought I could achieve this by doing `if (error[0].innerText == "This Field is required")` then place to the right of the div and if not put else where, however it is not working. If I enter an invalid response to digits it will put the required error message at the bottom of the page from then on and vice versa for if I leave the field blank at first.

I am very confused on why this would be happening and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another stack over flow post. Apparently errorPlacement is called once per element which is why it was not updating. Here is the stack overflow post that resolved this for me: [jQuery Validation Plugin: Invoke errorPlacement function when onfocusout, keyup and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400607/jquery-validation-plugin-invoke-errorplacement-function-when-onfocusout-keyup/2401513#2401513)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery on `error` function

```
$('.class').error(function(){
  //When .class having an error do this
  $('.errorMessage).addClass('show'); /*Maybe*/
});
```

Comment: Well I'm using .validate({. Does this work with it or is this something completely seperate

Comment: Are you mean you add `required` at the input area?

Comment: I am using .validate({ errorPlacment, errorClass, and stuff)  I am using required and digits and just want the error messages in different locations. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that before

Comment: Em i really don't know what to do,but maybe you can using jQuery to append some <p> saying the ERROR message you need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

did you thought on use bootstrap? I used and it was the best option for a clear code

go to this link
http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-control-validation

Comment: I am just an intern at a company so I don't think they would let me just add bootstrap onto the existing code base for a small thing like this